# How to show specific admin menu to specific user role?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, menus, user-roles

I hope you are well how I can show a specific admin menu to a specific user role already created by the WooCommerce shop manager. how to show only a custom specific plugin (admin menu page) in this role.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. But you can change the visibility of the menu depending on the role with the plugin 'Adminimze'; maybe this helps you.

Comment: hii.. i need to change added admin menu page capability. by default plugin added the capability manage_options i need to chnage how i can change without edited plugin file.

Comment: It is hard to change them, hard to maintain. Maybe you should think in the direction to create new roles and add the capabilities to these roles to get more difference. Or you remove menu items for roles, not for capabilities, like Adminimize.